# Singleton with properties in Swift 3

Tags: singleton, swift3

In Apple's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6) (updated for Swift 3) they give the following example of the Singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance: Singleton = {
        let instance = Singleton()

        // setup code

        return instance
    }()
}
```

Let's imagine that this singleton needs to manage a variable array of Strings. How/where would I declare that property and ensure it gets initialized properly to an empty `[String]` array?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

For me this is the best way, make init private. **Swift 3 \ 4 \ 5 syntax**

```
// MARK: - Singleton

final class Singleton {

    // Can't init is singleton
    private init() { }

    // MARK: Shared Instance

    static let shared = Singleton()

    // MARK: Local Variable

    var emptyStringArray = [String]()

}
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but to match Swift 3 syntax, "sharedInstance" should be changed to just "shared".

Comment: You don't need to cast the type though

Comment: @thibautnoah you need, in init or directly

Comment: Unless there is a regression from swift 2 to swift 3 you don't

Comment: The type after shared can be omitted, right? `static let shared = Singleton()`

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi What do you mean with omitted ?

Comment: @YannickSteph you do not have to write `static let shared: Singleton = Singleton()` instead you can just write `static let shared = Singleton()`

Comment: The answer is correct but according to the Swift 3 syntax `override` should be applied to `init` method.
`override private init() {}` instead of just `private init() { }`

Comment: Something to keep in mind, because this is static, it'll be initialized on application startup. An exception will therefore prevent the application from starting.
Also if you're accessing resources from a database or service on startup, this can have a serious performance impact on your application startup.

Comment: @Nitesh Yes, but It's up to you to manage the instance of your singleton

Comment: @RomanN No you can't override init because it does not inherit a class.

If you can do that, with this example 
```final class Singleton: NSObject {

    private override init() { }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to mock Singleton?

Comment: @HossamGhareeb remove final for the test

```class Singleton { ... } / class MockSingleton: Singleton { ... }```

Comment: would be great if they did like in Kotlin lang (`object` instead of `class`, that's all you need for Singleton, nothing more)

Comment: @Nitesh static variables are lazily initialized in Swift - they're not all initialized at startup

Answer (score 59):

You can initialize an empty array like this.

```
class Singleton {

    //MARK: Shared Instance

    static let sharedInstance : Singleton = {
        let instance = Singleton(array: [])
        return instance
    }()

    //MARK: Local Variable

    var emptyStringArray : [String]

    //MARK: Init

    init( array : [String]) {
        emptyStringArray = array
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer a different approach, this one will do fine.

```
class Singleton {

    //MARK: Shared Instance

    static let sharedInstance : Singleton = {
        let instance = Singleton()
        return instance
    }()

    //MARK: Local Variable

    var emptyStringArray : [String]? = nil

    //MARK: Init

    convenience init() {
        self.init(array : [])
    }

    //MARK: Init Array

    init( array : [String]) {
        emptyStringArray = array
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this method not work in an extension?

```extension Cache {
    static let sharedInstance: Cache = {
        let instance = Cache()
        return instance
    }()
}```

Comment: Interesting that Apple uses `class var` in iOS 10 for singletons (e.g. UIApplication). Would their implementation be the same as this?

Comment: I prefer singleton init methods as `private` methods not even `internal`. This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.

Comment: @KumarC You are correct, would not it solve the issue if we add a ```private``` in ```init```.

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander Could you bring more informations?

Comment: I'm not sure that accessing to `emptyStringArray` thread safe, but on the other hand value types in swift are thread safe, so `emptyStringArray` is array, arrays is value type, perhaps it's thread safe.

Answer (score 30):

As per the apple's documentation: [In Swift, you can simply use a static type property, which is guaranteed to be lazily initialized only once, even when accessed across multiple threads simultaneously](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html).

```
class Singleton {

    // MARK: - Shared

    static let shared = Singleton()
}
```

With initialization method:

```
class Singleton {

    // MARK: - Shared

    static let shared = Singleton()

    // MARK: - Initializer

    private init() {
    }

}
```

Comment: why the init() is not private ?

Answer (score 0):

Any initialisation would be done in an init method. No difference here between a singleton and a non-singleton.

Comment: An additional code snippet that directly answers the question would make this answer more helpful.