# How do I send data between multiple view controllers swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have 6 view controllers, where you input your name on screen 2, and i want it to carry through so I can put the users name that they input as apart of an email body. Say you input your name as "Kevin", then on screen 5 where you click send, the email display comes up and the subject has "Name: 'Kevin'" and so on. Theres no tutorials on how to do this, only for view controllers that are side by side, and this one has to pass data from 2 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can UserDefault

**In Screen 2**

set value

```
 UserDefaults.standard.setValue("your user name", forKey: "UserName")
 UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

**In screen 5**

```
 let strUserName =  UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"UserName") // this your input
```

You need to remove value from UserDefault while it not required

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "UserName")
```

**OR**

```
 UserDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "UserName")

 UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: where would i input this? under viewDidLoad or under class? also what code would i have to type in to get it to be included in the email body? Im using a UITextField so would need to pass what ever the user inputs

Comment: you can put in viewDidDisappear or textFieldDidEndEditing.

Comment: let strUserName is your input value then you need to set as email body.

Comment: Using `synchronize()` has been useless since iOS8. It's explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a singleton class and store the date in it? Here is one example for it:

[Singleton with properties in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953317/singleton-with-properties-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to just share String is to use UserDefaults. You can save something to it and get it on another screen.

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(value, forKey: key)
UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key)
```