# unable to create Singleton object for my class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, singleton

I am creating one class for `Text2Speech` and for that, I am creating a Singleton object to use it as a single object at many places in my project but I am getting the below error:

**My Code:**

```
static let sharedInstance = Text2Speech()
```

Or

```
static let sharedInstance : Text2Speech = {
    let instance = Text2Speech()
    return instance
}()
```

**Error I am getting:**

> Cannot use instance member 'Text2Speech' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available

I am doing the same declaration for the SingleTon object at many places but Only in this class, I am getting the above error.

I have already checked [this question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953317/singleton-with-properties-in-swift-3) but no luck on any solution.

Something wired or messed in that class.

**Edit:**

**Text2Speech Class:**

```
class Text2Speech: NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    var delegate: Text2SpeechDelegate?
    var utteranceCount : Int
    var isMale : Bool
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    static let sharedInstance = Text2Speech()
    
//    static let sharedInstance : Text2Speech = {
//        let instance = Text2Speech()
//        return instance
//    }()
    
    override init() {
        self.utteranceCount = 0;
        self.isMale = false
        super.init()
        synth.delegate = self
    }
    
    func Text2Speech(_ text: String){
        utteranceCount += 1
        let myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        myUtterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0.005
        myUtterance.rate = 0.5
        myUtterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.0
        if self.isMale{
            myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language:"en-GB")
        }
        synth.speak(myUtterance)
    }
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didStart utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        delegate?.Text2SpeechConvertor(synthesizer, didStart: utterance)
    }
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        utteranceCount -= 1
        let seriouslyFinished = utteranceCount==0 ? true:false
        delegate?.Text2SpeechConvertor(synthesizer, didFinish: utterance, seriouslyFinished: seriouslyFinished)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More context is needed. `class Text2Speech { static let sharedInstance = Text2Speech() }` compiles without problems.

Comment: @MartinR I have added whole Text2Speech Class can you please check my updated answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a function with the same name as the
class. Here is a minimal self-contained example demonstrating the 
problem:

```
class Text2Speech {
    static let sharedInstance = Text2Speech()
    // error: cannot use instance member 'Text2Speech' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

    func Text2Speech(_ text: String) { }
}
```

Apparently, the compiler takes `Text2Speech()` as an attempt to 
call the function. Renaming the function (e.g. to `func text2Speech`) solves the issue.

Note that the Swift convention is to start type names with
uppercase letters and function names with lowercase letter.

Comment: Yes @Martin you are right its problem of Same function name as Class name. Now its working i have changed it to `func text2Speech` and its working now, Thanks for your quick response.