# Call a nested function in Swift with a button

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to call retrieveData() when a user presses a button.

```
extension ViewController {

    func doOAuthFitbit2() {

        let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
            consumerKey:    "*****",
            consumerSecret: "*****",
            authorizeUrl:   "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize",
            accessTokenUrl: "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token",
            responseType:   "code"
        )

        oauthswift.accessTokenBasicAuthentification = true
        oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = getURLHandler()
        let state = generateState(withLength: 20)

        let _ = oauthswift.authorize(
            withCallbackURL: URL(string: "smart://oauth-callback")!,
            scope: "profile nutrition",
            state: state,
            success: { credential, response, parameters in
                self.retrieveData(oauthswift)
        },
            failure: { error in
                print(error.description)
        }
        )
    }

    func retrieveData(_ oauthswift: OAuth2Swift) {
        print("retrieveData")
        let _ = oauthswift.client.get(
            "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json",
            parameters: [:],
            success: { response in
                let jsonDict = try? response.jsonObject()
                print(jsonDict as Any)
        },
            failure: { error in
                print(error.description)
        }
        )
    }
}
```

I have the following in ViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func btnRetrieveData(_ sender: Any) {
    retrieveData(oauthswift)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'OAuthSwift?' to expected argument type
>   'OAuth2Swift'

Which I assume is because "oauthswift" is declared inside the doOAuthFitbit2() function.

Do I need to refactor the code so the retrieveData() function is nested inside the doOAuthFitbit2() function? how would I call that in ViewController.swift?

Answer (score 0):

Your `oauthswift` property is local to the `doOAuthFitbit2()` function, and thus you cannot access it from the button method (or any other method). I'd suggest to start with, you could add it as a global property that `doOAuthFitbit2()` updates, e.g.:

```
var oauthswift: OAuth2Swift!
// ^ declare global variable

func doOAuthFitbit2() {

    oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
    // ^ reference the global variable and set it up here
        consumerKey:    "*****",
        consumerSecret: "*****",
        authorizeUrl:   "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token",
        responseType:   "code"
    )

    oauthswift.accessTokenBasicAuthentification = true
    oauthswift.authorizeURLHandler = getURLHandler()
    let state = generateState(withLength: 20)

    let _ = oauthswift.authorize(
        withCallbackURL: URL(string: "smart://oauth-callback")!,
        scope: "profile nutrition",
        state: state,
        success: { credential, response, parameters in
            self.retrieveData(oauthswift)
    },
        failure: { error in
            print(error.description)
    }
    )
}
```

You can then do:

```
func retrieveData() {
//                ^ you don't need to pass an arg here, since it's globally accessible
    print("retrieveData")
    let _ = oauthswift.client.get(
        "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json",
        parameters: [:],
        success: { response in
            let jsonDict = try? response.jsonObject()
            print(jsonDict as Any)
    },
        failure: { error in
            print(error.description)
    }
    )
}
```

That said, there are more stable ways of implementing this - like a [shared instance (singleton)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39860897/1214800) that can be accessed globally throughout the application, [shared delegates/protocols](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148448/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming), or the [iOS keychain APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html). I won't get into those though - you'd need to do some learning and reading there.