# How to get a instance of UITodayViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, swift4

I am using a common class for my app and an extension Today.

I am also using a preprocessor macro: iOS 8 Extension How To Detect Running.

How can I get  a instance of UITodayViewController?

```
 #if WIDGET
    // here       
 #else
    //....
 #endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Singleton with properties in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953317/singleton-with-properties-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

If your asking how to make a singleton from a UIViewController:

Add a static instance to an extension.

```
extension UITodayViewController {
    static let shared = UITodayViewController()
}
```