# Declaring Alamofire.SessionManager once in the class for using it in various utility functions inside the class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

So I am making a utility class for Alamofire networking for my project.

I have various functions inside it like:

```
func createAccount()

func login()
```

I want to use fixed time limit for all these function's reuqests and responses.

I have known that this works for the same:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
        AFManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

However, I don't want to initialize AFManager in all the utility functions. I want a single declaration of it. How can I do the same? I am not able to get it.

Comment: Are you looking for "Singleton" pattern? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953317/singleton-with-properties-in-swift-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called a [property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html):

```
class NetworkManager {

    private let manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
        retrurn Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }()

    func createAccount() {
        manager.request(...)
        ...
    }

    func login() {
        manager.request(...)
        ...
    }

}
```